# Validating issuer fails when site is reached under different alias as configured in the jwt bearer handler

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt, openiddict, asp.net-core-security

I have web api which uses jwt bearer authentication. The implementation ([openiddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core)) which creates the jwt uses the the current url as issuer.

```
services
    .AddOpenIddict()
    .UseJsonWebTokens();
```

I configured the jwt authentication handler to use a valid issuer.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://test/";
        ...
    });
```

When I reach the site under `http://test/` I get an access token with the issuer set to `http://test/`. As the `Authority` matches the issuer the requests will be authenticated.

When I reach the site under `http://125.124.35.21/` I get an access token with the issuer set to `http://125.124.35.21/`. As the `Authority` doesn't match the issuer the request won't be authenticated.

> I want in both cases to be able to authenticate the request.

Now I saw that according to [the jwt rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.1) the `iss` claim is optional.

My question is if I can set `ValidateIssuer` to false for this purpose, if I open a security hole when I do that and if there is an more recommended alternative?

```
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://test/";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ...
        }
    });
```

Which configuration is used to resolve the `.well-known/openid-configuration`?The `Authority`? Hopefully not the issuer because that would mean that everybody can issue a token and use it with my api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked into the code which generates my access token and found out that it only takes the current uri when no configuration value was set.

https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/blob/120a7ea9a14a33fad292cf4a11b4077118fab21f/src/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/OpenIdConnectServerHelpers.cs#L198

```
public static string GetIssuer(this HttpContext context, OpenIdConnectServerOptions options)
{
    var issuer = options.Issuer;
    if (issuer == null)
    {
        if (!Uri.TryCreate(context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host +
                               context.Request.PathBase, UriKind.Absolute, out issuer))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The issuer address cannot be inferred from the current request");
        }
    }

    return issuer.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

So when I configure openiddict I can just set the `Issuer` property.

```
services.AddOpenIddict()
    ...
    .Configure(options =>
    {
        options.Issuer = "http://test/";
        ...
    });
```

And when I add the authentication services I can also just set the `Authority` property.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://test/";
        ...
    });
```

---

It seems like that when no valid issuer is configured the `Authority` is taken to validate the issuer. But I've found no code to support that claim.

Maybe its hidden in `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll`

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to set `ValidateIssuer` to `false`.

---

As the [JWT RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) says that the `iss` (Issuer) claim is optional.

> The "iss" (issuer) claim identifies the principal that issued the
> JWT.  The processing of this claim is generally application specific.
> The "iss" value is a case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI
> value.  **Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.**

---

The [OAuth 2.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) doesn't mention an issuer or in what format tokens are at all.

---

The uri to resolve the `.well-known/openid-configuration` is configured by the `MetadataAddress` property. If this property is not set it seems like the `Authority` property is used to build the uri.

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/b3e4bf382c9676e2d912636b7ee0255cad244e11/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerPostConfigureOptions.cs#L37

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.MetadataAddress) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Authority))
{
    options.MetadataAddress = options.Authority;
    if (!options.MetadataAddress.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        options.MetadataAddress += "/";
    }

    options.MetadataAddress += ".well-known/openid-configuration";
}
```

---

And as the public key to verify the token is stored in the `.well-known/jwks` file which is prefixed by the `MetadataAddress`, it should be save to ignore this claim, if you don't wan't to excluce certain issuers where all share the same configuration file. But I can't think of such a case.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution would be to include all known aliases in the `ValidIssuers` property of the `TokenValidationParameters`. But I don't think this is a good idea as you would probably forget some aliases.

For example in different subnets you might can reach the service under different ips or different dns aliases.